# large Images Canvas with FF

Tags: html, image, firefox, canvas, large-files

i have a Pronlem with large Image Files to display it in a Canvas with FileReader. With small Images it works fine, in Chrome with large images too. But in Firefox it displays nothing and after toDataUrl its gives a black Image. The Image size is 5580 * 8333 (8mb).
If i load the dataUrl from FileReader in a Image Tag it works too.

```
var reader  = new FileReader();

    reader.onloadend = function () {
    preview.src = reader.result;
console.log(reader.result);

                        var canvas = document.getElementById("resize");
                        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

                        var image = new Image();
                        image.src = reader.result;
                        image.onload = function() {

                            var MAX_WIDTH = 400;
                            var MAX_HEIGHT = 300;
                            var tempW = image.width;
                            var tempH = image.height;
                            if (tempW > tempH) {
                                if (tempW > MAX_WIDTH) {
                                   tempH *= MAX_WIDTH / tempW;
                                   tempW = MAX_WIDTH;
                                }
                            } else {
                                if (tempH > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                                   tempW *= MAX_HEIGHT / tempH;
                                   tempH = MAX_HEIGHT;
                                }
                            }
                            image.width=tempW;
                            image.height=tempH;
                            canvas.width = tempW;
                            canvas.height = tempH;
                            ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, tempW, tempH);
                        };

                      }

                      if (file) {
                        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                      } else {
                        preview.src = "";
                      }
                    }
```

Thanks for help

Comment: recommend optimising your images using jpg-optimiser.com or tinypng.com before loading them into your application. the images will be the same just way smaller in size

Comment: I load the Image into the canvas because i want to resize the Image clientside

Comment: like i say the images will be exactly the same dimensions but smaller FILE size you should really read more about optimising images

Comment: The browsers all have different max sizes they support for canvas. Yours is hitting the FireFox limit unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks fopr the Quick response